# How can I filter a string from a pcap file using python?

Tags: python, filter, wireshark, pcap

I have some large pcap files (~100MB each) and I want to filter out those packets which contain strings from a dictionary file (txt). The dictionary file is formatted like:

```
line 1: word1
line 2: word2
line 3: word3
line 4: word4
```

So, if word1 is present anywhere in the pcap file (should be in the TCP payload?), I want to remove that string or simply want to remove that packet from pcap file.
Is there any way to achieve this efficiently (fast enough)?

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete lines from a file if it contains a string? You might want to clarify what you are trying to do, what you've tried so far, and show some input and expected output. If you have memory constraints, could you state the amount of memory you're constraint to?

Comment: I don't have any memory constraint for now. The input file is a normal pcap file containing traffic of various hosts in a network. When I followed the TCP stream of some hosts, I found many improper contents (adult contents) which I don't want in the pcap files. So, I want to strip out those packets/frames or lines from the pcap file.

Comment: Since stackoverflow is no code writing service I've reduced your question to that you are looking for a way to modify pcap with Python and that you will implement the specific modification yourself. When interpreted like this your question is a duplicate of [PCAP modification with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250981/pcap-modification-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. For other users, Tshark can be useful to search a string inside a tcp stream. Following can be useful if you want to search for a string and want to output the ip addresses of the source and destination:

```
tshark -r <capture-file> -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e data |\
 grep `echo -n "<ascii-string>" | xxd -p` |\
 cut -f 1,2
```

So, to achieve what I wanted in the question, following bash script can be useful:

```
value=`cat bad_words.txt`

for i in ${value[@]}; do tshark -r my_test.pcap -T fields -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e data |\
 grep `echo -n $i | xxd -p` |\
 cut -f 1| uniq > $i; echo $i; done
```