# Modify bytes in Scapy script

Tags: python, scapy

I have a pcap file where I have packets like this :
Ether()/IP()/TCP()/Raw ([this one for example](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=mms.pcap.gz))

I'd like to choose random 10 packets in the pcap file and modify 3 bytes in the Raw layer located at the same position in the whole 10 packets, and then save the pcap.
I did some tests but didn't achieve anything, I don't think it's the right way to do:

```
pkt = rdpcap('file.pcap')

for i in pkt:
  if i.haslayer(TCP) and i.haslayer(Raw):
    list_pkt.append(i)

rdm_list = random.sample(list_pkt,10)

for i in rdm_list:
  org = i[Raw].load
  new = org[:15] + '\xdd\xdd\xdd' + org[18:]
  i[Raw].load = new
```

Any help please?

Comment: can you include a sample of the file.pcap so I can load it into a list

Comment: Ok johnashu, I edited pointing towards an example pcap

Comment: Hey dude I have been having a play around but I didnt succeed yet.. I am busy now but please read this :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250981/pcap-modification-with-python

Comment: Thx I'll have a look to this post! Meanwhile if you find how to do I'll appreciate your help :)